# MKPinAnnotationView callout not showing

Tags: objective-c, ios, mapkit

This is a pretty strange issue, but I think it might be that I don't really understand the finer points of MapKit yet. I have a bunch of annotations on a page. When I select one, I want a callout to appear. I have `[pinView setCanShowCallout:YES];` and I know that when I tap the pins, they're being selected because the corresponding delegate method `mapView:didSelectAnnotationView` is being fired. However, no callout pops up! What gives? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have an object that adheres to the `MKAnnotation` protocol backing your `MKPinAnnotationViews`?

Comment: Yep, my `MapPin` class has `@interface MapPin : NSObject <MKAnnotation>` at the top of its header.

Comment: Have you implemented the `- (NSString *)title` method in this object to return the text that should appear in the callout?

Comment: `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "MapKit/MapKit.h"
#import "Place.h"

@interface MapPin : NSObject <MKAnnotation>
{
    NSString *title;
    NSString *subtitle;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    Place *place;
}
@property (readonly,nonatomic,copy)NSString* title;

@property (readonly,nonatomic,copy)NSString* subtitle;

-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)name andLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)location;
-(id)initWithPlace:(Place *)aPlace;
-(Place *)place;
@end`

That's my interface.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it to work. I think I accidentally deleted my `setCanShowCallout` method call when I was trying to figure out why it wasn't working. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

For a callout to work, the MKAnnotation object must respond to the @property title.  If you have a title and canShowCallout == YES, then you should be good to go.